# Variável igual a ela mesma caso o resultado da lógica for falso

Tags: php

Considere o seguinte código:

```
$a = $b > $c ? $c : $b;
```

A questão é, se $b é um conjunto de operações, caso o resultado da lógica $b > $c for falso, terei que repetir toda a operação existente em $b.

Fiz da seguinte forma, mas gostaria de saber se ainda há outra maneira:

```
$a = $b;
$a = $a > $c ? $c : $a;
```

Comment: isso é um "abuso" do operador ternário uma vez que o seu código está menos eficiente que um `if()`. Não faz sentido fazer a comparação lógica e uma atribuição que não é necessária. `if($a > $c) $a=$c;` (não atribui nada no `else` (por não ter o mesmo)).

Comment: @Kyllopardiun o else seria sim necessário no primeiro exemplo mas não no segundo. A questão é o primeiro exemplo, se $b é um conjunto de operações, não é legal voltar a escrever tudo caso o resultado da logica seja falso, é essa a questão.

Comment: Filipe, eu não consigo entender a sua questão. Me parece algo óbvio: se quero manter um resultado lógico até certo ponto o que devo fazer? **Armazenar** e é exatamente o que fez.

Answer (score 2):

Fica mais fácil de entender atribuindo valores nas variáveis:

```
$b = (2 * 4); // 8

$c = 6;

$a = $b;

if ($b > $c) $a = $c; // true, redefine o valor de $a = $c

echo $a; // resulta 6

//-----------------//

$b = (2 * 4); // 8

$c = 10;

$a = $b;

if ($b > $c) $a = $c; // false, não faz nada, e mantem $a = $b

echo $a; // resulta 8
```

Answer (score 2):

O seu segundo exemplo é o melhor a fazer, visto que, você diz que para ter o valor $b tem que fazer calculos o melhor é guardar temporariamente na variavel para não perder tempo a repetir o cálculo. No entanto eu não usaria o operador ternário visto que se fizer desta forma ficará bem mais facil de entender para a espécie humana:

```
$a = $b;
if( $a > $c )
 $a = $c;
```